# problemas en orden de funciones no culmina una antes de iniciar otra en javascript Asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

tengo un botón editar en una vista al presionarlo me llama una ventana modal la cual carga varios controladores entre ellos un combo con varios estados el cual depende de la información recuperada de la base de datos, el problema que presenta es que ejecuto las funciones pero antes de culminar de recuperar los datos de la base de la primera función ya comienza la ejecución de la siguiente que depende del resultado de la anterior, al ejecutar paso a paso veo que de la función recuperardiario salta a llenarcomboestados y no esta instrucción no hace nada ya que aun no retorna la información set("cboEstados", rpta.estado)

el código lo tengo así

```
function Editar(id) {
    set("txtidlptdiario", id)
    recuperarlptdiario(id);
    llenarComboEstados(false, get("txtesestactual"));
    llenarComboIncon(true);
    estadoant();
    validar();
}

function recuperarlptdiario(id) {
    var idlptdiario = get("txtidlptdiario")
    fetchGet("LP_TDiario/recuperarlptdiario/?idlptdiario=" + idlptdiario, function (rpta) {
        set("txtconsecutivo", rpta.consecutivo)
        set("txtnumerotramite", rpta.tramite)
        if (rpta.finalizado != null && rpta.finalizado != 0)
            document.getElementById("CheckFinaliza").checked = 1;
        else
            document.getElementById("CheckFinaliza").checked = 0;

        set("cboInconsistencias", rpta.inconsistencia)

        set("cboEstados", rpta.estado)
}

function llenarComboEstados(callback, nombreestado) {
    var estact = get("txtesestactual");
    pintarCombo("InfComun/listarestados?nombreestado=" + nombreestado, "IdEstado", "Estado", "cboEstados", false, function () {
        callback()
    });
}
```